# React-native: index.js file missing from node_modules\@react-native-community\masked-view

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am getting this below error while building react-native app.
`@react-native-community/masked-view` and `@react-navigation\stack` are up to date but not sure why this package is not being resolved while building.

```
error: Error: While trying to resolve module `@react-native-community/masked-view` from file `C:\..\..\node_
modules\@react-navigation\stack\src\views\MaskedViewNative.tsx`, the package `C:\..\..\node_modules\@react-n
ative-community\masked-view\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module
 field that could not be resolved (`C:\..\..\node_modules\@react-native-community\masked-view\index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:


my package.json 

{
  "name": "appname",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
   ..
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.6",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^9.3.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^7.8.7",
    "@react-native-firebase/functions": "^7.4.9",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^7.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "5.10.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "5.10.2",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "5.3.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "5.8.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "5.11.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.2",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-global-props": "^1.1.5",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-spinkit": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**Update and temporary solution:**

I have tried uninstalling `@react-native-community/masked-view` a few times.
I have tried deleting node modules folder, clearing cache using commands like `npm cache clean --force, react-native start --reset-cache` but nothing worked so far.

Then I realized `@react-native-community/masked-view` package is missing index.js file from installation.

I copied js folder and index.js file from another project for `@react-native-community/masked-view` and project starts building.

[image]

I am not sure why this folder and index file is missing from the installation itself.

Any help on this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you do `yarn install` then restart the app using `react-native start --reset-cache`, since all of your dependencies are matching mine.

Comment: I did that few times now. also tried clearing cache / deleting node modules but nothing worked so far

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting/#missing-extensions-in-metro-configuration

Comment: @satya164 sourceExts was not added to my metro.config.js file and I added and reset cache.. problem still exists. I pasted my metro.config.js file here. let me know if you need to see any other file.

Comment: if I remove @react-navigation/stack and stop using stacknavigator then project runs fine. so I think something related with the @react-navigation configuration

Comment: @satya164 FYI, I did some troubleshooting related search and have updated metro config file again but still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me perfectly,  hope it helps anyone out there too.

**1. Delete node_modules
2. Delete package-lock.json
3. npx expo prebuild
4. run npx expo start -c**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).